# Crear un test via que pruebe necesario un lock a una interface

Tags: c#, tdd

Tengo un codigo parecido a esto:

```cs
public class Processor:IProcessor
    {
        private readonly IFactory _Factory;
        private readonly Inonthreadsafe _nonthreadsafe;
        private object lock;

        public Processor(IFactory Factory)
        {
            _Factory = Factory;
            _nonthreadsafe = _Factory.CreateNonThreadSafe();
        }


        public void Process(string s)
        {

            lock (s)
            {
                _nonthreadsafe.NoSafeThing();

            }           


        }
    }
```

Como puedo escribir un test que demuestre la necesidad y funcionamiento del lock si estoy mockeando la interface `Inonthreadsafe`

Comment: en el codigo que nos muestras, como asignas la instancia de `_nonthreadsafe` ?

Comment: tenia un fallo ya lo he corregido